# How to properly center the text?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to center the text in the middle of JQM page, vertically and horizontally. Using 1.4.5, default theme.

In my .css I have:

```
.splashDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="splashDiv" data-role="page">
    Please wait...
</div>
```

The result is:

[image]

The text is vertically centered only if I remove `top: 0` directive in developer tools(although not perfectly centered).

[image]

My question is what is the proper way according to JQM architecture to have what I want? I am not looking for quick/dirty workaround, unless there is no other way.

UPDATE

[image]

Comment: The tag jquery-mobile is necessary because I would like to follow the ideology of JQM and not do trick things. I mostly hope there is some data-role or class to help fix this issue.

Comment: if you need a splash screen before libraries have been loaded, you don't even need to put your div inside a page, put it just as the first element inside the body, with inline styling As soon as jQM has been loaded, i would suggest you to use the jQM Loader with a little bit custom styling

Comment: @deblocker: that is also great idea, worth to try! thank you :)

Comment: @deblocker by default, when jQM is loaded, it wraps body's content in ui-page div. Best solution is to initialize jQM manually on `mobileinit` event. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26920806/1771795

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26110087/1771795

Comment: @Omar: great info! I always learn something new from you! BTW, here is a comparison with the loader: https://plnkr.co/edit/WnQuaK15oeMcd7HoTGQW?p=preview

Comment: @deblocker you're welcome :) I guess the difference is due to page's padding, because jQM loader is a direct child of body. I haven't touched jQM in long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your splash div within a jQM page instead of making it the page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="cont" role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="splashDiv" >
          Please wait...
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>  

.splashDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/bqOGOL)**

Comment: Now what is separating me from happiness is the top bar, which I don't need on that page. Please see my update screenshot.

Comment: @Pablo this is the padding 1em in ui-content, remove it, that's it.

Comment: @Pablo, Omar is correct. I have updated my demo to remove padding: http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/bqOGOL

Answer (score 0):

```
.splashDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding:0;
}
```

Use this it will align your text vertically center.

Comment: -50 drives it out of screen. 50 brings it slightly below center, due to padding, coming from JQM's `.ui-content` class and something which is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it.
Your HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="cont" role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div class="splashDiv" >
        <span>Please wait...</span>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Your CSS

```
.splashDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
.splashDiv span {
    margin: 0;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/malek_m/pen/oZJXoa)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the following css:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto;
```